# toStringHelper() is undefined for the type Objects

Tags: guava

I am using Guava.
i get a "the method toStringHelper() is undefined for the type Objects error" in eclipse.
i was working with no errors when suddenly these errors started coming.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return Objects
        .toStringHelper(this)
        .add("id", this.id)
        .add("custid", this.custid)
        .toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that your eclipse marks as erroneous?

Comment: Are you sure that you imported and used `com.google.common.base.Objects` but **not** `java.util.Objects`?

Comment: yes i have imported "import com.google.common.base.Objects;"

Comment: 'code'  @Override
    public String toString() {
 return Objects.toStringHelper(this).add("id", this.id).add("custid", this.custid)
  .toString();
    }

Comment: Another thing that might help with figuring out what the issue is: what, if any, other methods on `Objects` do _not_ cause this issue when called in the same context (i.e. in the same `toString()` method)?

Comment: got the problem fixed. Have posted it below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check that you don't have Google Collections (the predecessor to Guava) on your classpath anywhere, e.g. `google-collect-1.0.jar`. It has a version of the `Objects` class that doesn't have the `toStringHelper` methods.

Another weird possibility is that you have a generic type `Objects` defined somewhere in the same context, e.g.:

```
import com.google.common.base.MoreObjects;

/**
 * In this class, "Objects" is a generic type parameter like "T",
 * just more confusing.
 */
public class Foo<Objects> {

  public String toString() {
    return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
        ...
  }
}
```

Seems unlikely, but....
[Guava docs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html)

Comment: Nice suggestion. But nope i dont find any other google jar in the project classpath :(

Comment: Edited with another possibility, though it seems more likely that something is whack with Eclipse than that you were doing this and didn't notice. =)

Comment: fixed the problem. Have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. It seems to be your Eclipse that screws up. Do a full clean/rebuild of your project, and/or restart your Eclipse and your system. It is voodoo, I know, but it often helps when Eclipse starts producing senseless errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so got the problem fixed now.
Apparently eclipse when deploying a web project adds osgi libraries one of them had a backdated version of guava without the ToStringHelper method. Removed that and no problems anymore.